# Need help on reducing the swaying(body roll) on my 2019 Ecosport TDCi?

Tags: ford, suspension, steering, handling

I own 2019 December made TDCi EcoSport, i feel nervous around corners while taking a sharp turn, this wasn't an issue with a prefacelift ones made around 2013-2017, should i change the suspension like stiffer dampers or lower stiffer springs,etc. what can I do to improve the cornering ability, handling is fine and steering response is adequate but the body roll is what making me nervous?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've got to ask a question of you ... how much do you want to spend on this endeavor? (ie: very little; moderate amount; sky is the limit) The pocketbook will always dictate what can and cannot be done with any vehicle.

Comment: I can spend some decent amount if required. What are my options?